# What is the difference between the Recording and Simple controllers in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, controller, record, recording, user-activity

What is the difference between the Recording and Simple controllers in JMeter?

I read [this](https://www.guru99.com/controllers-in-jmeter.html) article. It says the following.

> **Recording Controller:**
> JMeter can record your Testing steps; a recording controller is a placeholder to store these recording steps.

> **Simple Controller:**
> Simple Controller is just a container for user request.

But I was able to use the `HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder` to record user actions into the `Simple Controller`. So, does it mean that the `Recording Controller` is the same as the `Simple Controller` + the `HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are just "containers" for the recorded [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers), from test execution perspective there is no difference at all

You're free to use any [Logic Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers) as the recording target

[image]

- Recording Controller and Simple Controller - will act just as "containers"
- [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) - the recorded sampler(s) will be repeated as many times as the number of loops you set
- [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/while-controller-jmeter) - the recorded sampler(s) will be repeated until the condition resolves to `true`
- [Transaction Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) - will generate a synthetic Sample Result with cumulative response time of all child(ren) sampler(s)
- etc.

Personally I would recommend using [Recording Template](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#test_plan_building), apart of using Recording Controller it comes with pre-defined "good" configuration when it comes to excluding requests to embedded resources, pre-defined HTTPS domain and so on.

[image]